# Failed to decode output: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=0, offset=32, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.0.7)

Tags: upgrading, proxy-contracts, contract-upgrading, dsproxy

When I try to call some of the unset getters through Proxy, I get this error in Remix

```
Failed to decode output: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=0, offset=32, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.0.7)
```

Or call any functions, leads to the prompt that transaction could fail and if I force send the transaction, in etherscan It shows a status of **X Fail**, Nothing else why it's failed or reverted

Using Openzeppelins' *UpgradableProxy.sol*

Comment: Can anyone solve this issue. I have the same issue